# how to change image size in react native image slider box

Tags: javascript, react-native, androidimageslider

I am using this library - [react-native-image-slider-box](https://github.com/intellidev1991/react-native-image-slider-box)

I want to change my image size, now it's too big. How can I change it?

Any idea...

Here is my code:

```jsx
<SliderBox
    images={list}
    sliderBoxHeight={300}
    autoplay
    circleLoop
    onCurrentImagePressed={(index) => {
        console.warn(`image ${index} pressed`);
    }}
/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you share your preview screen?

Comment: sorry mean ?? my code??, I t is very large

Comment: try adding following props: `resizeMethod={'resize'} resizeMode={'cover'}` to `SliderBox`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: resizeMode change karun bagh na from `cover` to other values

Comment: yes yes zhal Thank You (Khatarnak coder = ketan)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image height inside the slider box using this property:

```
ImageComponentStyle={{height: '50%', width: '97%', marginTop: 5}}
```

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider-box) links to the below example (example 8)

Your final code will look like this:

```
<SliderBox
images={list}
sliderBoxHeight={300}
autoplay
circleLoop
onCurrentImagePressed={(index) => {
    console.warn(`image ${index} pressed`);
}}
ImageComponentStyle={{height: '50%', width: '97%', marginTop: 5}}
/>
```